# MYSQL UPDATE - 1 DAY off DATE field?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table which stores featured from and to for objects. I would like to unfeature an item via ajax.

The way I have decided todo that is to set any featured rows for an object called to -1 day from now so its no longer featured.

However my query isn't working.

```
UPDATE `Movie_Featured` SET `to` = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE id > 0 $where
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a '`;`' before the `where` clause, in your query :

```
UPDATE ... INTERVAL 1 DAY); WHERE ...
```

I suppose you should remove that '`;`', because it's the character that's used to separate queries ; which means you actually have two queries, here :

- `UPDATE`Movie_Featured`SET`to`= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

  - which is a valid query, but will update every lines of your tabale
- and `WHERE id > 0 $where`

  - which is not a valid query, and will cause an SQL error.

Comment: UPDATE `Movie_Featured` SET `to` = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE id > 0

Indeed ;( Whoopsie

Comment: Having someone else look at your code often helps, in that kind of situations ;-)